# newform.aspx Source= URL has query parameters with &

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, redirect

Currently, I have a filtered SP page with parameters `FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=XXX`.

Adding a new item to the NewForm.aspx - My Source URL is:

```
Source=xxxxx.sharepoint.com/process/SitePages/Plan.aspx?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=customer%27s%20TradeShow%20-%2020
```

After I hit Save the Redirect removes the & and everything after it, so returns this:

```
xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/process/SitePages/Plan.aspx?FilterField1=Title
```

I want to have the redirect keep the parameters so that the page is filtered again.

How can I all the parameters to stay in the source redirect?

Comment: What is the Plan.aspx page? Is it a page with a list view web part or others? Could you provide detailed steps to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a list via a URL parameter, you can use OOTB QueryString (URL) Filter web part. 
[How to use Query string filter web part in SharePoint 2016/2013/Online](https://www.spguides.com/query-string-filter-web-part-in-sharepoint-2016/)